# How to create/copy an Object in Java faster?

Tags: java, object

I want to copy an object in java without copying reference.

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = o1;
```

But o2 should not copy reference of o1. So any changes done in o2 must not affect o1.

How do we do this in java ?

Comment: clone() method is specific to Object class. If I have to copy object of some specific class, I think clone won't work.

Comment: @Setu, as pointed out by others below, you need to override the `clone` method for specific classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `clone()` method which will create a copy of entire object graph (deep copy) and create a new object.

Note: Every class will inherit default `clone()` implementation from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) class. But you must override the method to perform copy depending on the contents of your object.

Just FYI:

> The default Object.clone() is a shallow copy. However, it's
>   designed to throw a CloneNotSupportedException unless your object
>   implements Cloneable.
>
> And when you implement Cloneable, you should override clone() to make
>   it do a deep copy, by calling clone() on all fields that are
>   themselves cloneable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method to clone the object:

```
Object o2 = o1.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need copy other classes than Object, make a copy constructor or static factory method. Effect is something like this:

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
MyClass o2 = new MyClass(o1); // in constructor make new object with data from o1 attributes
```

or

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
MyClass o2 = MyClass.makeCopy(o1); // make static method for create new copy (similar like above)
```

Don't use clone. -> [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)